# Typoscript condition for empty variable

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there a way to use Typoscript condition to assign a different value to a TypoScript TEXT if a GET variable is empty ?

Something like that :

```
xxxx.1 = TEXT
[globalVar = GP:print != ""]
xxxx.1.value = Absent
[else]
xxxx.1.value = Present
[end]
```

Of course here the `!= ""` doesn't work, so what should I use instead ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example with "if":

```
1 = TEXT
1 {
    value = Absent
    override = Present
    override.if {
        isTrue.data = GP:print
    }
}
```

Comment: But is this is a condition? It looks like a complicated default value?

Comment: That is not a condition. Also note that this will be cached. A condition could be [globalVar = GP:print = 1]. So your link would have to append "?print=1".

Comment: @Phpdna This looks like a complicated default value but afaik its the only way I could check if a GET-param is set. Note, that if "?print=0" will be evaluated as false and the value "Absent" will be used in this example.

Answer (score 2):

With *globalString* it's also possible to use a Regular Expression as comparison. Depending on the context this might also be a viable solution.

```
[globalString = GP:test = /.+/]
# This is only evaluated if GP:test contains one or more characters
[global]
```

Answer (score 0):

At first there is no != in typoscript. You can only use >, <, = for conditions.

For your needs you can use this:

```
[globalVar = GP:view = print]

[end]
```

Just define a Variable "view" which can become the value "print".

- You can also work with "if" and "override", "ifEmpty" and "required".
- Here are some other examples of conditions in typoscript: http://www.pi-phi.de/19.html

Comment: I know this answer is old, but finally since Version 6.0 in Typo3 there is a != operator: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id23 :)

Answer (score 0):

I found for instance with a cookie, you can set no value and it will see it a empty?

```
[globalVar = _COOKIE|user_test_score = ]
```

So maybe also:

```
[globalVar = GP:view = ]
```

Not sure if it is intended but works for cookies anyway.